# Spreadsheet-like input in html?

Tags: html, input, spreadsheet, copy-paste

I'm writing a webpage (PHP/html/css) and I would like to let my users enter a lot of data, always consisting of the same information: `day`, `hour`, `title`, `details`, `class`. For this, I'd need a `<table>` with `<input>` fields, but with the additional feature that it looks like a spreadsheet, and that users can copy-paste (blocks of) rows and move rows around, as they will often need to enter a lot of similar data.

I feel like re-inventing the wheel if I'd have to write this from scratch. How would I best do this? Is there any standard package (e.g. in javascript) allowing such functionality?

**Note:** I don't need any spreadsheet functionality (formulae etc.), just the copy/paste/move on input. So a full spreadsheet package would probably be overkill and also clutter the interface.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've used [Handsontable](http://handsontable.com/) before - very easy-to-use.

Comment: Aha! That looks very good, the only feature I miss there is dragging selected rows with the mouse (cut&paste already works). If there is any similar package which can also drag rows, that'd be perfect, otherwise I'll just go with this one. Thanks!

Comment: And thanks to the keywords on the link you gave, I managed to find this overview http://roberto.open-lab.com/2010/01/30/javascript-grid-editor-i-want-to-be-excel/ so I consider the question answered now. :-)

Comment: Not free for commercial use though.